# Get Visible IndexPath UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How to get `visible IndexPath` while `scrolling` in `collectionView`,I referred many [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281451/iterate-over-all-the-uitablecells-given-a-section-id-swift/32626614#32626614),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649920/uicollectionview-current-visible-cell-index) But `indexPathForCell` is not supported in Swift.

Answer (score 21):

Have you tried delegate function?

```
public func indexPathsForVisibleItems() -> [NSIndexPath]
```

or

```
collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems()
```

these must give you what you wanted.

Answer (score 11):

Swift, **safer way to get visible Items**:

```
if let indexPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems {
    //Do something with an indexPaths array.
}
```

Answer (score 9):

try this

**On delegate**

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
for cell in yourCollectionViewname.visibleCells()  as [UICollectionViewCell]    {
   let indexPath = yourCollectionViewname.indexPathForCell(cell as UICollectionViewCell)

    NSLog("%@", indexPath)
}
}
```

**Choice-2**

**on Button Click**

```
  var point : CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView:yourCollectionViewname)
var indexPath =yourCollectionViewname!.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point)
```

**Get visible All Items**

you can use indexPathsForVisibleRows

**Returns an array of index paths each identifying a visible row in the receiver.**

> - (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleItems;

```
var visible: [AnyObject] = yourCollectionViewname.indexPathsForVisibleItems
var indexpath: NSIndexPath = (visible[0] as! NSIndexPath)
```

Answer (score 5):

> This will work fine.

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    let visibleIndex = Int(targetContentOffset.pointee.x / collectionView.frame.width)
    print(visibleIndex)

}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use method of UICollectionView as :

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: value1, section: value2)
```

Comment: Your answer is completely irrelevant to the question